# How to update a Vue repo's Github Page after the first deploy?

Tags: vue.js, github-pages

I have a Vue.js repo.

I have followed tutorials like this to get it deployed on GitHub pages: https://betterprogramming.pub/create-and-deploy-a-vue-js-app-to-github-pages-706dbf7bc2c4

These always request that you create a branch named `gh-pages`.

After I deploy this to Pages, I seem to run into a wall on how to update this beyond that initial push. When I make any changes in `main`, I try to merge that into `gh-pages` but I get the message `unable to merge unrelated histories in this repository`.

How do you continually update a Vue.js github pages page?

Comment: It seems a git issue, due your commits are not related beetween your branch, if you want to force use `--allow-unrelated-histories`